# C pointers, minimum and maximum values

Tags: c, pointers, max, minimum

I need to write a function that gets num1, num2 and num3 as parameters. Once the function is done running, the parameters(num1, num2 and num3) sent to the main function should change so that num1 contains the smallest value, num2 contains the second biggest value and num3 the biggest value. I also need to write a swap function and use it.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void SmallBig(int* num1, int* num2, int* num3);
void swap(int* x, int* y);
void main()
{
    int *num1, *num2, *num3;
    *num1 = 1;
    *num2 = 69;
    *num3 = 22;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", *num1, *num2, *num3);
    SmallBig(*num1, *num2, *num3);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", num1, num2, num3);
    system("PAUSE");

}
void SmallBig(int* num1, int* num2, int* num3)
{
    if (*num1 > *num3 && *num2 > *num3 && *num1 > *num2)
    {
        swap(num1, num3);
        swap(num2, num2);
        swap(num3, num1);
    }
}
void swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

These are the errors I get:

```
Warning 1   warning C4047: 'function' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int' 
Warning 2   warning C4024: 'SmallBig' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1   
Warning 3   warning C4024: 'SmallBig' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2   
Warning 4   warning C4024: 'SmallBig' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3   
Error   5   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'num1' used   
Error   6   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'num2' used
```

### Error   7   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'num3' used

Please help me fix the program!
Thank you. - Amnon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The errors and problems

About your errors:

```
int *num1, *num2, *num3;  // you define 3 pointers to int but let them unitinialised !
*num1 = 1;                 // you write something to the poinded adress, which might be random !!
*num2 = 69;
*num3 = 22;
```

As you use the pointers without initializing them (you only initialize the values that are pointed to), you get this error message

Then your second `printf()` prints the pointers and not the pointed values.

And finally, SmallBig() will work only in a small number of cases !

## Solution

Use integers in `main()`, not pointers:

```
int num1, num2, num3;
num1 = 1;
num2 = 69;
num3 = 22;
printf("%d %d %d\n", num1, num2, num3);
SmallBig(&num1, &num2, &num3);   // use the address 
printf("%d %d %d\n", num1, num2, num3);
```

I almost forgot your `SmallBig()` function ! There, continue to use pointers as you did.  But you have to foresee more cases:

```
   if (*num1 > *num3) 
        swap (num1, num3); 
   if (*num1 > *num2) 
        swap (num1, num2); 
   if (*num2 > *num3) 
        swap(num2, num3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have is here

```
SmallBig(*num1, *num2, *num3);
```

You are passing the deferenced pointers as arguments - these have type `int` not `int*`. Your `SmallBig` function is expecting pointers so call it as such

```
SmallBig(num1, num2, num3);
```

Your code should at least now compile with this change.

The second main problem is that you are writing values to uninitialised memory when you do this

```
int *num1, *num2, *num3;
*num1 = 1;
*num2 = 69;
*num3 = 22;
```

Writing to uninitialised memory is undefined behaviour and at best will result in a segfault. A safer approach would be

```
int num1,num2,num3;
num1 = 1;
num2 = 69;
num3 = 22;
```

and then pass the addresses of these `int` variables to the functions expecting `int*` arguments. If you don't like this way you will need to dynamically allocate your pointers. You cannot write to what is pointed at by an uninitiliased pointer without expecting trouble.

Finally, this line

```
swap(num2, num2);
```

does nothing useful